# Deleting Orphans with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have been struggling with this issue, couldn't find a solution yet.

I have the following situation (I've cut non-necessary parts):

```
public class Company : Base // Base has Guid Id
{
    public virtual HeadQuarter  HeadQuarter { get; set; }
}

public class HeadQuarter : Base
{
    public virtual Company      Company     { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public CompanyMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).Column("CompanyId");

    References(x => x.HeadQuarter)
        .Column("HeadQuarterId")
        .Unique()
        .Cascade.All();
}

public HeadQuarterMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id)
        .Column("HeadQuarterId");

    HasOne(x => x.Company)
            .PropertyRef(x => x.HeadQuarter)
            .Cascade.All();
}
```

That generates two tables in my DB. I can insert a Company with a HeadQuarter. It works fine.

The problem is that when I remove a Company, the HeadQuarter doesn't get deleted. That's why I use cascading.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does the Headquarter table FK reference to Company get updated/altered when you delete the company?

Comment: @wvisaacs , in the company table, Headquarter has a FK with cascading:  On Update RESTRICT and On Delete RESTRICT

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, that the mapping should be inversed. Check the doc

#### [HasOne / one-to-one](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping#hasone--one-to-one)

> In the example below, we are mapping the relationship between a Car entity and a SteeringWheel entity. For our business rules, a Car will only ever have one SteeringWheel so we would map it like so:

```
public class CarMap : ClassMap<Car>
{
    public CarMap()
    {
        Table( "Vehicles.dbo.Car" );

        Id( x => x.CarId );
        Map( x => x.Name );
        Map( x => x.Year );

        HasOne( x => x.SteeringWheel ).PropertyRef( x => x.Car);
    }
}

public class SteeringWheelMap : ClassMap<SteeringWheel>
{
    public SteeringWheelMap()
    {
        Table( "Vehicles.dbo.SteeringWheel" );

        Id( x => x.SteeringWheelId );
        Map( x => x.Diameter );
        Map( x => x.Color );

        References( x => x.Car, "CarId" ).Unique();
    }
}
```

So, in our case, we would need the

```
public CompanyMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).Column("CompanyId");


    HasOne(x => x.HeadQuarter)
            .PropertyRef(x => x.Company);
}

public HeadQuarterMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id)
        .Column("HeadQuarterId");

    References( x => x.Company, "CompanyId" ).Unique();
}
```